# UDP a logical choice for transmitting small amounts of data out of a secure network?

Tags: network

Just, in general, if someone needs to send data that is (1) never bigger than the payload of a UDP packet, (2) does not need to reliably get there, sending UDP packets is the logical choice?

Even from within highly secure networks, a client can safely communicate its status to servers on the public internet with a burst of UDP packets, and there is no security risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using proper encryption and authentication (such as with DTLS, a TLS-like protocol that works over UDP), it should be completely fine. The standard caveats apply, for example message loss is possible, any datagrams with spoofed source addresses will still be received, etc. UDP itself is merely a transport protocol, so all confidentiality, authentication, and integrity must be done above it. In this case, the question becomes whether or not DTLS, QUIC, or whatever you use is sufficient for your needs, which is a different question.

Comment: I'm thinking, on a daily basis, sending CPU usage stats out via UDP. If sometimes a transmission does get to the server, no big deal.